# Xamarin Android app out of the box shows undefined Android.Support, Android.Views, Android.Content in MainActivity

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I needed to rebuild my fairly ancient Xamarin Forms app from scratch and in the process arrived at a situation where I had a new working iOS app but had needed to delete the draft Android app and start it again. So as a next step I added a vanilla Android app project out of the box and immediately what I saw was that (in MainActivity) Android.Support, Android.Views and Android.Content were undefined with wiggy red lines beneath -- for example in a reference to Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar.

Trying to solve the problem, I set each of Target Framework, Minimum Android Version and Target Android Version to Android 9.0 Pie (API Level 28). In SDK Manager I checked that Android SDK Location and Java SDK Location were 'Found' and that Android SDK Platform 28 was installed.

The following NuGets came installed along with the project, I deleted them and reinstalled them (removing bin/obj folders in between): Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils, Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs and Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.

I tried installing NuGets Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.*. And I added the Xamarin.Forms NuGet. I tried adding 'use' declarations.

None of this helped.

For comparison I separately installed a blank Android app solution-- it worked perfectly out of the box.

Android is pretty new to me - would be grateful for suggestions on fixing this.

The app has a .NET Standard 2.0 project, an iOS project, the (vanilla) Android project (all three with Xamarin Forms), and a .NET Standard 2.0 library project.

I'm using Visual Studio for Mac V8.5.4 (stable) on MacOS 10.15.3.

Comment: You might be using X.F 4.5 and they defaulted to AndroidX instead of support libraries. Try cleaning the solution (manually deleting all bin and obj folders), right clicking Android project in Solution Explorer and choosing "Migrate to Android X"

Comment: I'm on X.F 4.6 and will try it.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that the content of MainActivity.cs is quite different, depending whether the Android project is created separately or as part of a Xamarin Forms solution. Also the provided NuGets are different. So perhaps what I was trying to do, adding an Android app to an existing XF solution, is simply not allowed.

To fix the problem, I created an empty Xamarin Forms solution with Android and iOS projects, added a further empty library project, then in Finder replaced the content of all the project folders, except the Android one, with the content of the corresponding folders in my working solution (the one with a working iOS app).

Migrating to AndroidX is a good idea though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help, but you should migrate to AndroidX as soon as possible, nevertheless. Xamarin has [migrated to them](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-xamarin-essentials-go-androidx/), starting from Forms 4.5

Here is some more information about the libraries - [Introducing AndroidX for Xamarin](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/androidx-for-xamarin/)

There is a special NuGet package for the migration - [Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration). Also available is a built-in functionality in Visual Studio - [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/androidx-nuget-packages-are-stable/)

What I can suggest is you try to migrate to AndroidX libraries, since the old support libraries won't be supported from now on, and you will surely encounter some issues if not like this one, then something else will pop-up in the future.

Comment: AndroidX did not fix the problem but I appreciate the advice and will do the migration asap.  :)